# Question in Chrome Extensions Sample

Tags: javascript, xpath, google-chrome-extension

Can anyone explaing me this line in detail?

```
  // Find all the RSS link elements.
  var result = doc.evaluate(
    '//*[local-name()="rss" or local-name()="feed" or local-name()="RDF"]',
    doc, null, 0, null);
```

Best Regards,
Cetin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doing an XPath query to find if the current document *is an RSS feed* by checking for the presence of certain XML elements. ([Mozilla has a great run-down on XPath in JavaScript here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/introduction_to_using_xpath_in_javascript))

Here are some examples:

Take look at [the RSS Feed for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/3328884):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed .....
```

It's looking for that `<feed>` element.

Or for example the [slashdot.org main feed](http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot):

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" ...
```

It's looking for that `<rdf:RDF>` element.